# Can I travel to Serbia with a Romania student visa?

Tags: romania, serbia

Are you allowed to enter Serbia and Bulgaria with just a Romanian student visa without the need for a residence permit ?
Egypt passport

Comment: You hold what type of student visa? C (<91 days) or D (>=91 days)

Comment: D type, I heard the residence permit is mandatory for non eu passport holder tho ? I'm from Egypt

Comment: @NicolasFormichella Doesn't matter

Answer (score 2):

Per TIMATIC, a database used by airlines:

> Visa Exemptions: Passengers with a visa issued by Switzerland, United Kingdom, USA or an EEA Member State for a maximum stay of 90 days. The visa must be valid for the period of intended stay

So no, you do **not** need a visa